# More than one collapsible sections open

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with collapsible section on my WP site. My knowledge of the topic is close to zero, so I'm using code from w3schools but only one section works. If I add another one, the previous stops responding to clicks.

My code looks like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Text</h2>

<button type="button" class="collapsible">Some text</button>
<div class="content">
  <p><img src="adress"</p>
</div>

<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is unclear as to what you trying to achieve and what is not working exactly? can you please explain that.

Comment: I would like to insert a collapsible section, below it some text and media and then again another collapsible section. It would look like this:

[text]
[collapsible 1]
[text]
[collapsible 2]

When I put this code elsewhere on the same page the previous section stops responding, i.e. it does not expand.

Comment: Seems to be working as intended with this jsfiddle i created: https://jsfiddle.net/kys3qe7u/